# Api Dynamic String Request link

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api

I want to create a form where user inserts his Registration Plate number into a input form, and then make a api dynamicly query string request [https://app.website.co.uk/api/datapackage/data?v=2&api_nullitems=1&auth_apikey=xxx&key_VRM=[input](https://app.website.co.uk/api/datapackage/data?v=2&api_nullitems=1&auth_apikey=xxx&key_VRM=%5Binput) user value reg plate]. Then I would like to return a value based on that api enquiry.

get a value from api request based on dynamic query string request

Comment: Do you have a question about anything specific about this, or did you just want to let us know what you want? If you have a question, then please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ask it. Right now, there's nothing for us to act upon here.

Answer (score -2):

Unlike others who love playing the "I'm too literal to understand this" card, to me your question is pretty evident.

What you need is to capture the input from the field (this will vary based on how you're doing this, ie. Node.js + Express.js could do with bodyParser),  and then pass it as a string literal.

I literally did this a couple of  weeks back:

```
`https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/${dataGlobal.latitude}%2C${dataGlobal.longitude}?unitGroup=metric&key=PWGSFXBQZER8UU98UNPZ7WKGN&contentType=json`
```

the ${dataGlobal.latitude} is one of the  variables I'm passing in the request.

Disregard people who need to put others down to feel superior, and code on!